# How can I be a better soldier?

Tags: king-arthurs-gold

I've started playing [King Arthur's Gold](http://kag2d.com/), but I can't get the hang of the sword fighting.

It seems to me that you have to hold the left mouse button down for a few seconds and release at the right time and the right range to do any damage.  However, during these few seconds, the tutorial bots always kill me.  They seem to be able to attack much faster than me.  I tried simply clicking, but that didn't seem to do anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you still playing/interested in the game? https://kag2d.com - it's totally rewritten and really different. Could help you with 'being a better soldier'.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the only way to deal damage as a knight.  The charge up attack doesn't even do any extra damage I don't think (but I could be wrong); it's merely there to give you the 'lunge' that comes with it.  You can use that against builders or unguarded knights to avoid taking damage, because you can attack from farther away.

Just left clicking rapidly will do your basic sword attack, but the trick is getting the right combination of guarding and attacking to get a hit on your opponent.  If you're facing a decent knight, he will be doing the same.